# Eclipse CDT: How to save project-wide environment variables programmatically (permanently)

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

I am able to create project-wide environment variables programmatically to Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment page. However when I restart the workspace the environment variables are vanished.

The code I use to add new project-wide environment variables is here:

Global variables:

```
private ICConfigurationDescription cfgd = null;
private final MultiCfgContributedEnvironment ce = new MultiCfgContributedEnvironment();
```

Inside method:

```
ICConfigurationDescription[] cfgs;
    cfgs = new ICConfigurationDescription[] {cfgd};
    for (ICConfigurationDescription cfg : cfgs) { 
        ce.addVariable("PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR", dir, 
        EnvironmentVariable.ENVVAR_APPEND, SEPARATOR, cfg);
    }
```

I am looking for a way to keep the environment variables on the 'Environment page' after the workspace is restarted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, without using the internal classes/APIs, is:

```java
IContributedEnvironment environment = CCorePlugin.getDefault().getBuildEnvironmentManager().getContributedEnvironment();
ICProjectDescription projectDescription = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescription(project, true);
ICConfigurationDescription config = projectDescription.getActiveConfiguration(); // or any other configuration...

// Add variable to project configuration
environment.addVariable("PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR", dir, IEnvironmentVariable.ENVVAR_APPEND, null, config);

// Update project (description)
CoreModel.getDefault().setProjectDescription(project, projectDescription);
```

Note that using `null` instead of `config` adds the variable to the global/workspace environment.

Also note the different "operation", as defined in `IEnvironmentVariable`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own question. I include the code here if someone else has the same problem.

The solution is to use StorableEnvironment which stores env. vars to XML.

```
UserDefinedEnvironmentSupplier fUserSupplier = EnvironmentVariableManager.fUserSupplier;
StorableEnvironment vars = fUserSupplier.getWorkspaceEnvironmentCopy();
vars.createVariable("PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR", dir);
fUserSupplier.setWorkspaceEnvironment(vars);
```

Be aware though that

```
org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.EnvironmentVariableManager;
org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.envvar.UserDefinedEnvironmentSupplier;
```

Are internal API classes and therefore their use is not recommended because their implementation could change and affect the functionality of your code.